# error when using `sudo update alternatives`

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "usr/bin/java" "java" "usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" 1
update-alternatives: error: alternative link is not absolute as it should be: usr/bin/java
```

Help me out guys, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "usr/bin/java" "java" "usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" 1
```

should be:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java 1
```